# Designing relationship between entities to avoid additional (join) table

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have 2 classes `Citizen` and `Company`. Both of them have a collection of `Car`. Specific `Car` may be assigned to either `Citizen` or `Company` (only one at the time) and is owned by it. `Car` has no knowledge about it's owner. `Citizen` and `Company` are not related witch each other.

```
public class Citizen {

    List<Car> cars;
}
```

```
public class Company {
    List<Car> cars;
}
```

```
public class Car {
    //some fields
}
```

I would like to achieve something like this:
[db tables desing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEmHS.png)

I know it's not possible so I am wondering how to model it to be clean from both JPA & DB side.

I thought of using `inheritance` provided by Hibernate and creating additional classes like `CitzenCar` and `CompanyCar`. However, each inheritance strategy seems to introduce unnecessary performance drops.

What is the best way to deal with that kind of a problem?

Comment: In my opinion, there should be more details in the question. It might (or might not) help to start with an explanation of the relationships between `Car` and `Company`, and `Car` and `Citizen`, along with example views.

Comment: My guess is using inheritance to create a `CitizenCar` and `CompanyCar` is poor design. It might be better to have an additional table, possibly representing the role the car will  have.

Comment: I've added more information

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "owner_type")
@Table(name = "car_owner")
public class CarOwner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("company")
public class Company extends CarOwner {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("citizen")
public class Citizen extends CarOwner {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private CarOwner owner;
}
```